# Saving data in Google Sheets with Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to save data to Google Sheets using the following function:

```
// function to save data
function saveData() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
    var refresh_time = sheet.getRange('Testdata!A2:A').getValue();
  sheet.appendRow([refresh_time]);
}
```

The problem is that only cell A2 is saved, but not the whole range A2:A
This is probably due to the appendRow. Is there also a command like appendRange?

Answer (score 1):

To get the values in A2:A you should use getValues() and not appendRow but setValues().  However I don't think that is what you want.  A2:A are all the cells from column A except the first and may include empty cells.

Instead try this:

```
function saveData() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet1 = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName("Testdata");
  var refresh_time = sheet2.getRange(2,1,sheet2.getNumRows()-1,1).getValues();
  sheet1.getRange(sheet1.getLastRow()+1,1,refresh_time.getLastRow(),refresh_time.getLastColumn()).setValues(refresh_time);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**I found some issues on your code:**

1. If you check the usage of `getValue()`, it will only return a single cell (top left cell of the range provided).

> getValue() - Returns the value of the top-left cell in the range. The
> value may be of type Number, Boolean, Date, or String depending on the
> value of the cell. Empty cells return an empty string.

Instead you should use getValues() to retrieve values of multiple cells.

> getValues() - Returns a two-dimensional array of values, indexed by
> row, then by column. The values may be of type Number, Boolean, Date,
> or String, depending on the value of the cell. Empty cells are
> represented by an empty string in the array. Remember that while a
> range index starts at 1, 1, the JavaScript array is indexed from
> [0][0].

2. In Sheet Service, each array is represented as row in Google Sheets.  `appendRow()` can only accepts 1D array which means `appendRow()` can only append single row. Having multiple rows means multiple arrays or 2D array.

### Example:

[image]

If you retrieve the values of `A1:A8`, it will return:

```
[[1.0], [2.0], [3.0], [4.0], [5.0], [6.0], [7.0], [8.0]]
```

3. To retrieve multiple values excluding the empty cells, you can use `getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)` with the help of `getLastRow()` as `numRows`.
4. To append multiple values, you have to use `setValues()` with the help of `getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)` and `array.length`. `numRows` can be determine by counting the number of sub-array in your 2d array or `array.length` and `row` can be determine by using `getLastRow()`.

### Nitpick:

This lines of code works:

```
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
var refresh_time = sheet.getRange('Testdata!A2:A').getValue();
```

but it is more efficient if you declare another variable for handling **Testdata** sheet.

Your final code should look like this:

```
function saveData() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
    var testDataSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Testdata");
    var refresh_time = testDataSheet.getRange(2, 1, testDataSheet.getLastRow()-1).getValues();
    sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow()+1, 1, refresh_time.length, 1).setValues(refresh_time);
}
```

### References:

- [getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column,-numrows,-numcolumns)
- [Range.setValues(values)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)
- [Range.getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues)
- [Sheet.getLastRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getlastrow)
- [Spreadsheet.getSheetByName(name)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheetbynamename)
- [array.length](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length)